# WPF: How do I properly reference a style in a resource dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've created a separate styles.xaml file which looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="NewButtons" TargetType="Button">
        <!-- style code here -->
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In my App.xaml file, I'm adding it as a resource dictionary like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="CustomStyles">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/styles/styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

However, now I'm not too sure how to properly reference it as a style in one of my windows. I tried creating a button like this but it didn't work:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CustomStyles}" />
```

It gives me an error warning that says "An object of the type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary' cannot be applied to a property that expects the type 'System.Windows.Style'"

I get what this error means and I'm sure the fix is someone quite small, I just don't know enough of XAML syntax yet to know what that is.

Comment: You need to specify the key of the Style resource, not that of the ResourceDictionary : `<Button Style="{StaticResource NewButtons}" />`

Comment: With that I get an error that states "The resource NewButtons could not be resolved"

Comment: `x:Key="CustomStyles"` indicates that this is not a top-level ResourceDictionary. If you assign it directly to Application.Resources, it should work.

Comment: Gave it a try but received two errors. First error on Application.Resources is "Cannot set properties on property elements". Second error on ResourceDictionary is "Each dictionary entry must have an associated key".

Comment: `<Application.Resources><ResourceDictionary>...</<ResourceDictionary></Application.Resources>`

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the `ResourceDictionary` as the `Style` instead of the `Key` for the `Style`.

Try this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource NewButtons}" />
```

Comment: As stated in the comments above, I get an error message with that. ""The resource NewButtons could not be resolved".

Comment: In your question you are referencing CustomStyles not NewButtons.

Comment: Correct. And when I change the code to what you and Clemens both suggested, I get the error message "The resource NewButtons could not be resolved".